# Editing messages using discord.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

This problem is giving me a headache.

I'm trying to edit discord messages, but it just won't work.

I get the error: slotDisplayer.edit is not a function

```
exports["%slots play"] = function(args, data) {
    var frame_count = utils.getRandomInt(15, 25);
    var main_reels = utils.newReels(3);
    var slotDisplayer = data.channel.send(`You spent 1 on this slot.\n\nSpinning...`);
    slotDisplayer.then(function(msg){
        utils.nextFrame(main_reels, 0, 0, frameDisplay);
        return msg;
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
    console.log(slotDisplayer);
    function frameDisplay(res) {
        var f = res.frame;
        console.log(slotDisplayer);
        console.log(`|${f[0][0]} | ${f[0][1]} | ${f[0][2]} |\n|${f[1][0]} | ${f[1][1]} | ${f[1][2]} |\n|${f[2][0]} | ${f[2][1]} | ${f[2][2]} |`);
        slotDisplayer.edit(utils.generateFrame()).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
        if(frame_count > res.frame_index){
            var properIndex = res.index >= main_reels[0].length - 2 ? 0 : res.index;
            setTimeout(function(){utils.nextFrame(main_reels, properIndex,res.frame_index,frameDisplay);}, 200);
        } else {
            var payobj = utils.logic(res.frame);
            slotDisplayer.edit(`|${f[0][0]} | ${f[0][1]} | ${f[0][2]} |\n|${f[1][0]} | ${f[1][1]} | ${f[1][2]} |\n|${f[2][0]} | ${f[2][1]} | ${f[2][2]} |\n${payobj.message}`);
        }
    }
}
```

I need an example for editing messages in discord.js.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use .then().

```
data.channel.send("blah blah").then((msg)=>{
    //your code here! msg.edit will work here.
})
```

The reason for this is because channel.send() returns a Promise, as per the API: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send

Additionally, you can assign the message object to another variable in the .then() so you do not have to work with large amounts of awkward indentation.

Comment: Another alternative would be to await the message being sent.

Comment: Yesss. Thanks much!